# I sound like death when I am alone - Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I sound like death when I am alone,
>
> Though I am no longer made of bone.
>
> With a friend our shapes may range
>
> From the eyes of a serpent to the cars on a train.
>
> But that's just in my basic form.
>
> In other shapes, please be forewarned
>
> Blood will spill and heads will roll
>
> When I'm feeling critical.
>
> Think you know the answer yet?
>
> Maybe you should place a bet.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are

> Dice.

I sound like death when I am alone,

> One die.

Though I am no longer made of bone.

> Dice used to be made from bone.

With a friend our shapes may range
From the eyes of a serpent to the cars on a train.

> Nicknames for dice rolls: Snake Eyes (1 & 1), Boxcars (6 & 6)

But that's just in my basic form.
In other shapes, please be forewarned
Blood will spill and heads will roll
When I'm feeling critical.

> Dice can come in many shapes. Used in D&D and other games to assign hit points. Can get a "critical" hit if you roll the right number.

Think you know the answer yet?
Maybe you should place a bet.

> Dice used in casino games.

Comment: Well done! I'm not surprised this one was solved so quickly, but it was still fun to write