# I come in all shapes and sizes, and I can offer all sorts of prizes

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, lateral-thinking

> Give me a fruit, I'll turn it to pieces,
> A turn of bad luck, and your plan ceases.
>
> Mistaken for death, if I'm without friends,
> Bringing with a breath, success will I send.
>
> Let's not forget, the adventurer's quest,
> Eyes of the snake, and they'll become the best.

What am I?

Comment: Veeeery similar to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52148/i-sound-like-death-when-i-am-alone-riddle

Comment: I didn't even know this one existed. Pretty cool. I came up with the lines myself and everything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are

> A die (or several dice)

Give me a fruit, I'll turn it to pieces,

> Dicing a fruit (or a vegetable) is cutting it into pieces.

A turn of bad luck, and your plan ceases.

> "No dice" is an expression meaning there is no possibility of something.

Mistaken for death, if I'm without friends,

> A die (the thing we throw) can be mistaken for the word die (the thing about dying). When there are several, we talk about dice, which clears the misunderstanding.

Bringing with a breath, success will I send.

> Some people like to blow on dice they're about to throw for "good luck".

Let's not forget, the adventurer's quest,
Eyes of the snake, and they'll become the best.

> In role-playing games, dice are more than often a central part of the gameplay mechanism. A "snake-eye" is the worst result you can have (it's basically two 1).

Also,

> The first letter of each line spells out "Gamble"

Comment: Great job, I saw you post first. The third line isn't quite what I had in mind. It was in reference to a common phrase.

Comment: Since you already got it, the phrase I was thinking of was, rot13(Ab qvpr) for the third line.

Comment: I didn't know that expression, fixed it ;)

Comment: The title also describes the answer, and rot13(gur svefg yrggre bs rnpu yvar fcryyf tnzoyr). Moved from a separate answer as it should have been a comment to start with (I have a better idea of how the site works now lol